# How to fetch latest added document in a collection in Firebase / Google Cloud Firestore?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Using the web/JS platform, I want to retrieve the latest document added to a collection.

1. How do I accomplish this?
2. Do I need to append a timestamp when I save the data?
3. Does the server automatically append a timestamp in the background on `doc.add()`?

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data

```
db
  .collection("cities")
  // .orderBy('added_at', 'desc') // fails
  // .orderBy('created_at', 'desc') // fails
  .limit(1)
  .get()
  .then(querySnapshot => {
    querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
      console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
      // console.log('timestamp: ', doc.timestamp()); // throws error (not a function)
      // console.log('timestamp: ', doc.get('created_at')); // undefined
    });
  });
```

Comment: Specify the platform you are using

Comment: @AngusTay: What do you mean by "platform?" I am using the Web tab (which I think means Javascript) on the code at the link provided. And I'm using the Cloud Firestore (not the Realtime Database). Does that answer your question? Or were you asking something more specific?

Comment: I mean the language, ya, JS

Comment: @FrankVanPuffelen: Frank, you saw (and edited) my question but no answer? Ouch. That hurts. You are usually so helpful. I would think this would be a typical and fairly common use case? And the documentation is surprisingly sparse and silent on the topic. Is there any good answer or best practice to follow here yet?

Comment: You need to provide your own timestamp to sort on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try using the `onSnapshot` method to listen to change events:

```
db.collection("cities").where("state", "==", "CA")
    .onSnapshot(function(snapshot) {
        snapshot.docChanges().forEach(function(change) {
            if (change.type === "added") {
                console.log("New city: ", change.doc.data());
                //do what you want here!
                //function for rearranging or sorting etc.
            }
            if (change.type === "modified") {
                console.log("Modified city: ", change.doc.data());
            }
            if (change.type === "removed") {
                console.log("Removed city: ", change.doc.data());
            }
        });
    });
```

Source: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen

Comment: But won't that only pickup changes? What if the value is not changing and I want to initialize a Reactjs component upon loading at, say, `componentDidMount()` time?

Comment: When it got triggered, it means that the changes has already done on the cloud.

Comment: I know. But I'm looking for a way to query the cloud firestore for existing data without waiting for it to change. Because I need to load that data into my component immediately after the component mounts.

Comment: I mean the general workflow in plain word, for example, when page load, check new doc ... From step 1 to what you want to achieve

Comment: After the component mounts, I want to fetch data from the Firestore, then load that data into my component, then re-render the component with the newly fetched data.

Comment: You solved it. However, you omitted the part about needing to create my own timestamp manually on saving. But you nailed the code! +1. The listener became necessary because the query returned (`undefined`) before the promise completed.